# Increasing code execution time-efficiency using data.table and for-loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, data.table

**Problem:** How can I make the for-loop in below code run more time-efficiently? For this toy example it works in a reasonable amount of time. However, `unique_ids` will be a vector of approximately 8000 entries and the for-loop slows down heavily the computation. Any ideas? Many thanks!

**Purpose:**
Cluster retrospectively IIDs for each day into hop and top based on calculation logic in for-loop.

Initial Data:

```
   IID      ENTRY     FINISH     TARGET max_finish_target_date
1:      1 2020-02-11 2020-02-19 2020-02-15             2020-02-19
2:      2 2020-02-13 2020-02-17 2020-02-19             2020-02-19
```

Final (Target) Data:

```
 IID      Dates    ind_frist
 1:      1 2020-02-10             
 2:      1 2020-02-11 hop
 3:      1 2020-02-12 hop
 4:      1 2020-02-13 hop
 5:      1 2020-02-14 hop
 6:      1 2020-02-15 hop
 7:      1 2020-02-16 top
 8:      1 2020-02-17 top
 9:      1 2020-02-18 top
10:      1 2020-02-19 top
11:      2 2020-02-10             
12:      2 2020-02-11             
13:      2 2020-02-12             
14:      2 2020-02-13 hop
15:      2 2020-02-14 hop
16:      2 2020-02-15 hop
17:      2 2020-02-16 hop
18:      2 2020-02-17 hop
19:      2 2020-02-18             
20:      2 2020-02-19             
21:      3 2020-02-10             
22:      3 2020-02-11             
23:      3 2020-02-12             
24:      3 2020-02-13             
25:      3 2020-02-14             
26:      3 2020-02-15 hop
27:      3 2020-02-16 hop
28:      3 2020-02-17 top
29:      3 2020-02-18 top
30:      3 2020-02-19 top
```

**Code**

```
rm(list = ls())

library(data.table)

# Some sample start data
initial_dt <- data.table(IID = c(1, 2, 3),
                         ENTRY = c("2020-02-11", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-15"),
                         FINISH = c("2020-02-19", "2020-02-17", ""),
                         TARGET = c("2020-02-15", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-16"))

initial_dt[, ":="(ENTRY = ymd(ENTRY),
                  FINISH = ymd(FINISH),
                  TARGET = ymd(TARGET))]

initial_dt[is.na(FINISH), FINISH := as.Date(ymd_hms(Sys.time()), format = "%Y-%m-%d")]


initial_dt[, max_finish_target_date := pmax(FINISH, TARGET)]


# Specify target data shape and output format
unique_ids <- c(1, 2, 3) 

dts <- seq(as.Date("2020-02-10", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date(ymd_hms(Sys.time()), format = "%Y-%m-%d"), by = "days")

ids <- rep(unique_ids, each = length(dts))
len <- length(unique_ids)

final_dt <- data.table(IID = ids,
                       Dates = rep(dts, times = len))

# Calculation logic
# QUESTION: How can I make this part below run more efficiently and less time costly?
for (d_id in unique_ids){
  final_dt[(IID == d_id) & (Dates %between% c(initial_dt[IID == d_id, ENTRY], initial_dt[IID == d_id, max_finish_target_date])), 
                ind_frist := ifelse((Dates > initial_dt[IID == d_id, TARGET]) & (Dates <= initial_dt[IID == d_id, max_finish_target_date]), 
                                    "hop", 
                                    "top")]
}
```

Comment: You will want to set your unique key for `data.table`. You will also need to use the built-in `for i j` operation which is very light on memory and does not copy data. Have a look at the set family `for (i in from:to) set(DT, row, column, new value)` source:http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#fast-looping-with-set

Comment: The target data as presented in your question is different from the output of your for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibel alternative using a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-join:

```
final_dt[initial_dt
         , on = .(IID)
         , ind_frist := c("", "top","hop")[1L + (Dates > TARGET & Dates <= max_finish_target_date) +
                                             Dates %between% .(ENTRY, max_finish_target_date)]][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     IID      Dates ind_frist
>  1:   1 2020-02-10          
>  2:   1 2020-02-11       top
>  3:   1 2020-02-12       top
>  4:   1 2020-02-13       top
>  5:   1 2020-02-14       top
>  6:   1 2020-02-15       top
>  7:   1 2020-02-16       hop
>  8:   1 2020-02-17       hop
>  9:   1 2020-02-18       hop
> 10:   1 2020-02-19       hop
> 11:   2 2020-02-10          
> 12:   2 2020-02-11          
> 13:   2 2020-02-12          
> 14:   2 2020-02-13       top
> 15:   2 2020-02-14       top
> 16:   2 2020-02-15       top
> 17:   2 2020-02-16       top
> 18:   2 2020-02-17       top
> 19:   2 2020-02-18       top
> 20:   2 2020-02-19       top
> 21:   3 2020-02-10          
> 22:   3 2020-02-11          
> 23:   3 2020-02-12          
> 24:   3 2020-02-13          
> 25:   3 2020-02-14          
> 26:   3 2020-02-15       top
> 27:   3 2020-02-16       top
> 28:   3 2020-02-17       hop
> 29:   3 2020-02-18       hop
> 30:   3 2020-02-19       hop
> ```

This is the same as the output of the for-loop.

Some explanation: the part `1L + (Dates > TARGET & Dates <= max_finish_target_date) + Dates %between% .(ENTRY, max_finish_target_date)` creates an index vector of one's, two's and three's of equal length as the number of rows of `final_dt`; if you put that between square brackets after `c("", "top","hop")`, for each one you will get an empty string, for each two you will get `"top"` and for each three you will get `"hop"`.

Comment: hi, thanks that helped. could you please elaborate on the ind_frist syntax (I have not seen this syntax before)

Comment: @rkraft the part `1L + (Dates > TARGET & Dates <= max_finish_target_date) + Dates %between% .(ENTRY, max_finish_target_date)` creates an index vector of one's, two's and three's of equal length as the number of rows of `final_dt`; if you put that between square brackets after `c("", "top","hop")`, for each one you will get an empty string, for each two you will get `"top"` and for each three you will get `"hop"`

Answer (score 2):

Your loop doesn't produce the output you show. The following non-equi joins produce that output but could easily be adjusted for other rules (e.g. those from your `for` loop):

```
final_dt <- CJ(IID = initial_dt[["IID"]], Dates = dts)
final_dt[initial_dt, ind_frist := "hop", on = .(IID, Dates >= ENTRY, Dates <= FINISH)]
final_dt[initial_dt, ind_frist := "top", on = .(IID, Dates > TARGET, Dates <= FINISH)]
```

These joins should be very fast.

Result:

```
#    IID      Dates ind_frist
# 1:   1 2020-02-10      <NA>
# 2:   1 2020-02-11       hop
# 3:   1 2020-02-12       hop
# 4:   1 2020-02-13       hop
# 5:   1 2020-02-14       hop
# 6:   1 2020-02-15       hop
# 7:   1 2020-02-16       top
# 8:   1 2020-02-17       top
# 9:   1 2020-02-18       top
#10:   1 2020-02-19       top
#11:   2 2020-02-10      <NA>
#12:   2 2020-02-11      <NA>
#13:   2 2020-02-12      <NA>
#14:   2 2020-02-13       hop
#15:   2 2020-02-14       hop
#16:   2 2020-02-15       hop
#17:   2 2020-02-16       hop
#18:   2 2020-02-17       hop
#19:   2 2020-02-18      <NA>
#20:   2 2020-02-19      <NA>
#21:   3 2020-02-10      <NA>
#22:   3 2020-02-11      <NA>
#23:   3 2020-02-12      <NA>
#24:   3 2020-02-13      <NA>
#25:   3 2020-02-14      <NA>
#26:   3 2020-02-15       hop
#27:   3 2020-02-16       hop
#28:   3 2020-02-17       top
#29:   3 2020-02-18       top
#30:   3 2020-02-19       top
#    IID      Dates ind_frist
```